# UEFI Shell: Access disabled device

Tags: uefi

**Is there any way (by UEFI Shell commands or UEFI app) to access a device which was disabled in the "BIOS" menu?**

---

*Long Story:*

When I enable the UART in the "BIOS" menu I get the following lines when calling `devices`:

> ```
> 78 R - -  -  1  1 Serial(0x1)
> …
> 15A D - -  1  - - Serial(0x1)/Uart(115200,8,N,1)/UartFlowCtrl(Hardware)
> ```

The corresponding driver looks like this (output shortened)

> ```
>  Handle B5 (D40B5D18) ...
>  Driver Name    : <NONE>
>  Image Name     : FvFile(54891A9E-763E-4377-8841-8D5C90D88CDE)
>  Driver Type    : BUS
>  Managing       :
>    Ctrl[78] : Serial(0x1)
>      Child[15A] : Serial(0x1)/Uart(115200,8,N,1)/UartFlowCtrl(Hardware)
>    Ctrl[14E] : PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1C,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)
>      Child[158] : PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1C,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Uart(115200,8,N,1)/UartFlowCtrl(Hardware)
> ```

If the UART is disabled I do not get the device entries and the driver drives only the PciRoot.

I thought I might get the device by reinitialize the driver. But as it has no name I have no idea how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

No, if the device is disabled in the BIOS settings, then it is literally turned off, so it’s not just a question of loading a driver for it. Hardware configurations set by the BIOS are locked after the BIOS writes to them, so they cannot be changed by software later without a reboot. You have to change the BIOS setting to enable the device.

Comment: OK. What does the BIOS settings do what I cannot do from uefi shell? I understand that it is not only about loading a driver. However, is not there any way to turn on the device? I suppose that it is a question of accessing a certain memory area!?!